# What should be the query for delete field from mongo db collection on groovy language

Tags: mongodb, groovy, collections, jmeter

What should be the query for delete field from mongo db collection on groovy language
I am looking to delete parameter from collection.

normal mongo db query its working

```
db.users.updateOne({"userId.name":"LastName"},{$unset:{nationality:"",occupation:"",friendlyName: ""}});
```

but using groovy it doesn't

```
collection.deleteMany(eq("userId.name", "Lastname"),combine(set("nationality", ""),set("occupation", ""),set("friendlyName", "")));
```

with this query it doesnt work.

Comment: what is `collection`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this `combine` bit as for the user removal you don't need to [unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) the `nationality`, `occupation` and `friendlyName`

Consider using [MongoCollection.deleteOne()](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#deleteOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) function and provide only `userId.name` attribute like:

```
def deleteResult = collection.deleteOne(eq("userId.name", "LastName"))
```

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)